# Equivalent functions resulting in different derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something terribly obvious here so excuse me. I'm working with a formula that stylized looks like the below, where f is the PDF of a uniform distribution between zero and 1, and where $Q>1$.

$$\int_0^Q(Q-j)f(Q-j)dj $$

Equivalently, this can be written as $$\int_0^Qjf(j)dj $$ (Essentially both are finding a version of an expected value). However, the two derivatives w.r.t Q are different? The second equation gives $Qf(Q)$ and when $Q>1$, it equals zero, which is seemingly correct. When you're outside the range of the uniform, you're not changing the Expected Value anymore.

The first function's derivative results in $\int_0^Qf(Q-j)+(Q-j)f'(Q-j)dj$ and since f'(x) is zero, we can show as $$\int_0^Qf(Q-j)dj $$ which is obviously $>0$.

Again, I'm absolutely positive I'm making an embarrasing mistake, but I have no idea why these are turning out differently. They should both be 0 when Q>1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats! You've run into the Dirac $\delta$-function.

This "function" is mis-named; it is not literally a "function" but is instead the limit of a class of functions which can often have other nice properties; for example, Gaussian functions with unit integral are smooth, even functions which rapidly approach $0$:$$\delta_\sigma(x) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}~\exp\left(-{x^2\over2\sigma^2}\right).$$The key about taking the limit $\sigma\to 0$ is that we develop a symbol which can "stand in" for a function which obeys the general heuristic: $$\int_a^bdx~\delta(x)~f(x) ~``="~ \lim_{\sigma\to0} \int_a^bdx~\delta_\sigma(x)~f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}f(0) & \text{ if } a \lt 0 \lt b, \\
-f(0) & \text{ if } b \lt 0 \lt a,\\
 0 & \text{ otherwise. }\end{matrix}\right.$$We might take the values $\pm f(0)/2$ when $a=0$ or $b=0$ as well. All of this happens because the $\sigma\to0$ limit is "infinitely tall, infinitely thin, total integral $1$" for the Dirac $\delta$-function, and it's called a "function" because usually we leave the $\sigma$ subscript and the $\lim_{\sigma\to0}$ too: the "middle expression" here is accurate but we often write the one on the far left.

Letting $a = -\infty$ you can see that this is $0$ for $x < 0$ and $f(0)$ for $x > 0$, so the Dirac $\delta$-function is actually **the derivative of a step function** with height $f(0),$ which is why it emerged for you. So in fact $f'(x)$ is not $0$ uniformly but better expressed with one step "up" at 0 and one step "down" at 1, so the derivative is $\delta(x) - \delta(x - 1),$ and you get:$$\int_0^Qdj~\Big(f(Q - j) + (Q - j) ~\delta(Q - j) - (Q - j)~\delta(Q - j - 1)\Big)\\
=1 + 0 - 1 = 0.$$If you do not like this derivation, consider equivalently integrating $(Q - j)~f'(Q-j)$ by parts, lowering $(Q-j)$ and raising $f'(Q-j)$ to get $-(Q-j)~f(Q-j)\big|_0^Q - \int_0^Qdj~f(Q-j).$ The first term is 0 and the second cancels the term you've already found.

Comment: This will take a little while to wrap my head around, but thank you so much for taking the time here to walk me through it. I guess my only question is why doesn't that issue show up with the alternative way of defining the function?

Comment: @Kyle: because you didn't take a derivative in the alternative way of defining the function. Maybe this helps: since our function goes nondifferentiable for $Q-j = 1$ and is zero for $Q - j > 1,$ stop integrating over this space where it is zero and simply insert the endpoint on the bottom: the first expression you wrote is trivially equal to $\int_{Q-1}^Q dj~(Q - j)$ when we remove the domain where the integrand is 0 from the domain of integration. Now do the same trick that you've been doing of differentiating under the integral sign, and the bottom limit will give the same $-1$ correction.